# Can I use a UK tourist visa to visit Georgia?

Tags: visas, georgia-country, nigerian-citizens

I am Nigerian. I want to know if I can use a UK tourist visa to travel to Tbilisi, Georgia, from Nigeria.

Answer (score 3):

According to information of [Georgia Visa Portal](https://www.evisa.gov.ge/GeoVisa/en/VisaApp), you don't need a visa as long as you visit Georgia during validity period of your UK visa and for no longer than 90 days in consecutive 180 days.

> Holders of valid visa or residence permit of the country you have selected are exempted from visa requirements. You can enter Georgia without a visa for 90 days in any 180-day period. Please, note that you must present relevant valid visa or residence permit along with your travel document/passport at the moment of crossing Georgian border.
>
> Detailed information on visa free travel is available on the following website: [www.geoconsul.gov.ge](http://www.geoconsul.gov.ge).